# DynamoDb Query API Vs PartiQL - RCU's

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Working on a service which queries DynamoDB for items with a given Hash Key and multiple Range Key prefix filter(starts with).

We are making multiple query operation to dynamo with the Hash key and the required range key prefix. As we understand, Dynamo computes RCU's for each query and work out units based on payload size and then rounds off to nearest figure. If we use PartiQL and query for the Hash Key and all possible Range Key prefixes(starts with) in a single query expression,  Can we save RCUs?(avoid rounding overhead that comes with multiple small queries)?